# Subquery invalid result with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've an issue with the columns result from a subquery.

When I write the query:

```
select Q1.numi, Q1.sir from (select numi, sir from cust_vehicle where topg = 'VU') Q1
inner join (select id_contact, sir, ni from cust_contact) Q2 on Q1.sir = Q2.sir
```

I get 2 output columns (numi and sir).

But if I transform the query above as a subquery like:

```
select Q3.*
from (
select Q1.numi, Q1.sir from (select numi, sir from cust_vehicle where topg = 'VU') Q1
inner join (select id_contact, sir, ni from cust_contact) Q2 on Q1.sir = Q2.sir
) Q3
```

I get only the first column as output (the numi field).

Why do I have this behaviour?

For information, I use MySQL 5.6.11 on OS X 10.8

Comment: As a side note why are you using subqueries as far as I can see all you need is a basic join?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/162e8/3 .... Your query seems data outputting correctly. where u tried execute this thing? through any programming code?

Comment: I use the MySQL Workbench. It's weird.

Answer (score 1):

I found the origin of the problem. It's MySQL Workbench.
I opened a new SQL sheet and pasted my query in it. Now, all work fine.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Always been a big fan of the command line myself. If I was going ti use an IDE, it would be Toad, every other one I've used has been in some way unsuitable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cv.numi
     , cv.sir 
     , cc.id_contact
     , cc.ni 
  FROM cust_vehicle cv
  JOIN cust_contact cc
    ON cc.sir = cv.sir
 WHERE cv.topg = 'VU'
```

Comment: You don't think you're answering the OP's question do you? It strikes me that he knows how to get the information he wants. However, when he does something else, he gets an unexpected result and is asking why.